# 3D CNN model throwing a Negative dimension error-- dimension issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am creating a 3D CNN model with Height = 128, Width = 128, Channels = 3.The code for 3D CNN-

```
def get_model(width=128, height=128, depth=3):
  """
  Build a 3D convolutional neural network
  """
  inputs = tf.keras.Input((width, height, depth, 1))

  x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(inputs)
  x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

  x = layers.Conv3D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
  x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

  x = layers.Conv3D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
  x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

  x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D()(x)
  x = layers.Dense(units=512, activation="relu")(x)

  x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

  outputs = layers.Dense(units=4, activation='softmax')(x)

  model= keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="3DCNN")
  return model
```

So after creating the model function when I am trying to build the model it throws a value error

```
-ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling3d_5/MaxPool3D}} = MaxPool3D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NDHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?,126,126,1,64].
```

Code for building the model:-
#Build the model

```
model = get_model(width=128, height=128, depth=3)
model.summary()
```

Full Error-

```
   InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
       1879   try:
    -> 1880     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
       1881   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
    
    InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling3d_5/MaxPool3D}} = MaxPool3D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NDHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?,126,126,1,64].
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    14 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
       1881   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
       1882     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
    -> 1883     raise ValueError(str(e))
       1884 
       1885   return c_op
    
    ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling3d_5/MaxPool3D}} = MaxPool3D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NDHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes:

 [?,126,126,1,64].
```

What's the meaning of this error?? Is something wrong with my dimension??

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying `data_format` argument, a `Conv3D` layer considers the input shape as:

`batch_shape + (conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels)`

Which you have specified as:

`batch_shape + (width=128, height=128, depth=3, channels=1)`

Therefore you have a data which its' shape is `(128,128,3)` and has 1 channel.

As the convolution operation applies to the first 3 dimensions which are `(128,128,3)`, after first convolution by `kernel_size=3` the 3rd dimension (the one you specified as depth=3), shrinks to 1. Then in the next layer (`MaxPooling3D`) it can not get pooling by 2, because the shape does not fit. So, consider to change the depth dimension by larger numbers or change `kernel_size` parameter. For example input shape could be `(128,128,128,1)` or the `kernel_size` should change to something else like `(3,3,1)`.

P.S: If you have a RGB image, then number of channels is 3 and the last dimension should be set to 3. In 3D images there is another concept named depth (another dimension) which is different from channel. So:

- 3D Image RGB:       `(width, height, depth, 3)`
- 3D Image Grayscale: `(width, height, depth, 1)`
- 2D Image RGB:       `(width, height, 3)`
- 2D Image Grayscale: `(width, height, 1)`

Comment: So if I have 3 channels that are RGB so I set channels = 3?

Comment: Yes. You have used Conv3D which fits to 3D data. If you have 3D images for example, you likely have more than 3 depth (The shape may be (128,128,128,3) . But if you have regular images (2D) use Conv2D layers, and the input will be (128,128,3)

Comment: I am trying to predict Gestures that's why I am using 3D Conv. I have just 1 confusion if my channel is a different thing which is 3 for RGB then what is the depth. I used to think that the depth is the channel

Comment: If you have an RGB image, then number of channels is 3 and the last dimension should be set to 3. In 3D images we have another concept named depth (another dimension) which is different from channel. So, in 3D image you have (width,height,depth,channel) and in 2D image you have (width,height,channel). If it is grayscale the channel is 1 and if it is RGB the channel is 3.

Comment: Just a question can I take number of images as depth

Comment: Do you know how is the structure of a 3D image? Like CT Scans? or MRI? How did you produce 3D images of gestures? Would you please tell me the shape of one of your images?

Comment: Basically, I have a sequence of videos as Images. For example, suppose for left swipe by hand I have a sequence of 30 images these sequences are created from video, so can I use these 30 images as depth?? and each Image size is(128, 128, 3)

Comment: No. You have each image as a 2d with shape 28,28,3. If they are in sequence, you should use sequence models. In sequence models you have 30 samples as a sequence. Read more about it.

Comment: Please read this paper https://drive.google.com/file/d/12wq_bnz2MeZ1FCXzwQlAGhpYGMtPL1JL/view?usp=sharing they are creating 3D cnn here they are using number of frames as depth and proving that to 3D CNN instead of using RNN+CNN

Comment: Please see the architecture below of 3D CNN and T-CNN